# Cannot Serialize datas of format Json from a Jquery Dialog to Asp.net MVC 3 controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a little newbie problem that I cannot figure out, I am having a form that generated from a partial view from a asp.net controller, it is then displayed in a jquery dialog.

I have 2 buttons on the dialog (Save / Cancel)

On the save button, I want to serialize the inputs from the form to send it back to the Asp.net mvc actionController, however it doesn' t seems to work, the actioncontroller does not getting the model object from Jquery Dialog, I am using Jquery Serialize function for the form.

Here is the Script code:

```
<button id="btnDialog">Account Logon</button>

<div id="Logonform"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#Logonform");

        $("#Logonform").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Login',

            buttons: {
                Save: function () {
                    alert($("#Logonform").serializeArray());
                    alert($("#Logonform").attr('UserName'));

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#Logonform").serialize(),
                        datatype: "JSON",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#Logonform").html(result).dialog('open');
                        }
                    });
                },

                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }

        });

        $("#btnDialog").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account")",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Logonform").html(result).dialog('open');
                }

                });
        });
    })

</script>
```

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Logon");

        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return Json( new { result = "ok", user = model.UserName });
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_Logon");
            }
        }
```

the view:

```
@model JqueryDialogTest.Models.LogOnModel


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Models/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Échec de la connexion. Corrigez les erreurs et réessayez.")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Any comment from you to point out what wrong would be very grateful

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Logon action parameter from a LogonModel type to a string and deserializing it yourself in the action method using JavascriptSerializer. If that still does not work use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what (if anything) is being sent over in the POST.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, your proposal is a way to do it, however, I changed the script from data: $("#Logonform").serialize() to data: $('form').serialize(), it works perfectly, now the actionController gets the objet correctly, But now I come to another problem, there is no client validation on the dialog prior to sending the json form to the actionController method, any guess how to do it ?

Comment: Since you are using JQuery for the AJAX calls I would use JQuery for the validation. Here is some JQery docs on validation (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).